# PHP:update table automatically in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I am building a simple coupon code buying application with  apis.
Here is the work flow

1. User can select a coupon (getcoupon api)
2. If a coupon is obtained and its marked as `pre_book`  then go the payment api for the payment.
3. If payment is success then coupon marked as `booked`

This works fine but i need help in the following:

If user is `prebooked` the coupon and aborted the payment  i want to mark coupon code status as `avaliable` after sometime (say its 15 min) this should also happens when payment fails.

Structrue of coupon_code table

1.id-PK

2.coupon_code

3.status

Can i use a crone job for this?? but i don't think its possible because its not a periodic update .

Answer (score 1):

1. Save the datetime of the payment attempt in the database
2. Create a cronjob that runs every minute
3. Update the table and set the payment_date as NULL using the following WHERE in your update query `WHERE payment_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)`

Comment: So i need relation with payment table and coupo_code table??

Comment: no, just add a column to the same table called payment_date or when you want to keep a history of all payment attempts create a new table and join them

Comment: But running a crone job in every minute? is there any performance issue for that?

Comment: Depends on the number of coupon codes it needs to update. If it is none it should be ready in a split second. creating an index on the payment_date column will improve performance